# Can't get changes in file "php.ini" to take effect

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

I am building a new WordPress website on a new testing server.  The testing server using [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP), but it is the Windows 7 version.  The server is running great and the site is fine, but I'm trying to import an XML file with posts, into the new site.  I get the following error:

> Sorry, there has been an error. File is empty. Please upload something
> more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being
> disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller
> than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

The file was generated by the WordPress export plugin and is 8.92 MB

I checked my *php.ini* file located at *C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.21\php.ini*.

I updated the lines as follows:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 32M


; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 40
```

But it still does not show the new values when I try to update the file. It still says there are only 2M instead of the new 32MB. Why?

Comment: Did you restart the server ? Also add `post_max_size = 32M`

Comment: Hi, yes and I restarted the server but still no change.  Even in the MAMP phpinfo tab it shows the old values, like it's having zero effect?

Comment: I also added the post_max_size = 32M but nothing changes?  I tried adding the file to the wp-admin folder also, as another article said that might work but that does nothing either?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the file you are editing isn't getting loaded by PHP.

Run the following command to see which configuration file is loaded.

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Or try the `phpinfo()` function to get the correct file path.

Then apply your changes and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue some time. I had resolved the problem by editing the *php.ini* file located at */etc/php5/cli/php.ini* in a Linux environment. I think you will have a similar path for your WAMP. Otherwise, you may be running another web server like IIS, Nginx, Apache, etc. Please make sure that there is not another web server running in your Windows 7 environment.

Comment: user is not on Linux also there is no  need for OP to provide any service name to Stack overflow.